# How to print n number of string in c?

Tags: string, pointers, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
    char *name;
    int a;
    name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(name));
    printf("no. of names:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("enter the names:");
        scanf("%s",name);

    }

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("entered names are:%s\n",name);
    }

    return 0;
    free(name);
}
```

how to print n numbers of entered string in c am already asked this question but i dont got any proper answer any body known the answer please edit my code please if you run my code its displays last string only i dont know why please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of names. To  achieve what you are trying to do you can use either a static array with the maximum size or allocate the memory dinamically as in the following program.
Note that you should also test the return value of malloc... just in case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
   char **name;
   int a;
   printf("no. of names:");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   int i;
   if( a<=0 )
      return 0;
   name = (char**)malloc( sizeof(char*)*a);
   for(i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
      printf("enter the name:");
      name[i]=(char*)malloc( sizeof(char)*128);
      scanf("%s",name[i]);
   }
   for(i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
      printf("entered names are:%s\n",name[i]);
      free(name[i]);
   }
   free(name);
   return(0);
}
```

Note I had to cast malloc because the compiler that the OP is using raise the error " cannot convert from 'void ' to 'char ** ' " (which means that it's old enough..)

Comment: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char ** '
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
Error executing cl.exe.

Comment: ok I will cast it... what kind of compiler are you using ... it must be very old than

Comment: @R.A done the casting, modified the answer.... by the way modern compilers don't need it. What compiler are you using?

Comment: ya its working well .. bro can u explain me what is ** in this code?

Comment: i am beginner bro so i cant understand your program please gv me a explanation bro.. @jekyll

Comment: @R.A. char** used to create an array of char* which is an array of strings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49725/discussion-between-r-a-and-jekyll)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(name));
```

name is a `char*`, so `sizeof(name)` is the size of an address. Hence you are not allocating enough memory.

Just allocate more memory:

```
name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20); //allocating 20 bytes for the block that name will point tor
```

Comment: I can't edit the question, just copy paste into your editor. I told you what line needs to be replaced.

Comment: His application won't work in any case as he needs an array of names other ways the second loop will always show the last filled name.

Comment: i want output like this ->  no. of names: 3  enter the names: brokenheart arivu stackoverflow entered names are: brokenheart arivu stack overflow but output should be line by line

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wrong space allocation (answered by brokenfoot), you will not get the results you want because you are reading all the names over and over in the same variable `name`, and later printing the name input last `a` times:

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    printf("enter the names:");
    scanf("%s",name);
}
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    printf("entered names are:%s\n",name);
}
```

The right approach would be to use an array to store all the names, and later print them one by one. For example:

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
printf("Enter the names:")
scanf("%s",name[a]);
}

print("The entered names are: ");
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
printf("%s", name[a]);
}
```

Comment: name[a] crash my program if i run your its just close my compiler @lawrence

Comment: The code i provided is not a final solution. You can't just use it as is, it is just an example for you to understand what you need to do. You should declare the name array properly first and then use it. It seems you are just looking for the complete solution without the effort of understanding the problem.